# Is it possible to android to lost part of a command writen to a characteristic via BlueTooth via BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an adaptation for an android [app](https://androidaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), to communicate with a [remote control](https://github.com/sarunia/Med-Link-v4), which has some pre defined commands.
I've followed [this](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-3-117d3a8aee23) implementation to do the Bluetooth communication and it's working fine for sometime.
This app should communicate with the remote control every 5 minutes or less, and I've been using the app for almost 6 months now. The last week I've some command clashes problem and looking at the logs I couldn't identify why did that happened. The last time that this had happened the app was running for more than 24h, communicating with the remote control, without any communication issue.
Two of it's commands have some similar characters, the first one that have to be done, to establish the connection.

> OK_CONN

And an sniffer command which keeps the pilot awake listening for some sensor data:

> N

Looking at the logs I can see the answer for command N, after applying the command OK_CONN.
Is it possible for a Bluetooth command to lost part of it's data, during an established communication or am I doing something wrong when writing to a characteristic? Should I change the command names to avoid this kind of clash?

I'm using android 9, at a Sony XPeria XZ phone.

**Edit to clarify @Emil comment**

```
07:02:12.880 [BleThread] writing <OK+CONN> to characteristic 
07:02:12.368 [Binder:19249_F] [onCharacteristicChanged():274]: 
n command confirme
```

Looking at the logs I see that the last written command as an ok_conn but it has written only the N, this is been show as the last line, it has confirmed to receive the n command alone, instead of receiving the full data of ok_conn.
By name clashes I mean that maybe the last N of the ok_conn command is been accepted as the command.
I just realized what's going on, you can post that as an answer @Emil, my problem was at the logic that sends the first command, sometimes I send this command and the micro controller is not started yet, that's probably the reason of it getting only part of the command.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by name clashes, but Android will always write what you told it to write, without packet loss, as long as you follow the rules to never have more than one outstanding operation (always wait for callback before you send the next operation) and that your data must fit within the maximum length for the corresponding operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by name clashes, but Android will always write what you told it to write, without packet loss, as long as you follow the rules to never have more than one outstanding operation (always wait for callback before you send the next operation) and that your data must fit within the maximum length for the corresponding operation.